# Kubernetes single node cluster: dns not working after deploy new image

Tags: kubernetes

I am beginner in Kubernetes. I have testing VPS with Kubernetes cluster, deployed one pod with nginx and configuration:

fastcgi_pass php-fpm:9000;

...and one pod with php-fpm, service for php-fpm and nginx.

Everything works, but when I deploy new image php-fpm, pod recreating and running but nginx cannot resolv php-fpm.

Deploy new image:

```
kubectl apply -f php_deployment.yaml <- with new image version
```

This is my configs:

Nginx Dockerfile:

```
FROM nginx:alpine

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD ["nginx"]

COPY ./docker/nginx/nginx.conf /etc/nginx/nginx.conf
COPY ./docker/nginx/sites-available/ /etc/nginx/sites-available

COPY ./src/public /var/www/public

EXPOSE 80 443
```

PHP-FPM Dockerfile:

```
FROM php:7.4-fpm-alpine

COPY --from=mlocati/php-extension-installer /usr/bin/install-php-extensions /usr/bin/

RUN curl -sS https://getcomposer.org/composer-1.phar -o /usr/bin/composer && chmod 700 /usr/bin/composer

RUN apk --update --no-cache add vim bash

RUN install-php-extensions pdo_pgsql http

RUN mv "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini-production" "$PHP_INI_DIR/php.ini"

COPY ./src/ /var/www/

WORKDIR /var/www

CMD composer install ; php-fpm

EXPOSE 9000
```

Kubernetes - php_deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: php-fpm
  labels:
    app: php-fpm
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: php-fpm
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: php-fpm
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: php-fpm
        image: kdosiodjinud/php-fpm:2.0.6
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 9000
```

Kubernetes php_service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: php-fpm
spec:
  selector:
    app: php-fpm
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 9000
    targetPort: 9000
```

Kubernetes nginx_deployment.yaml

```
apiVersion: apps/v1
kind: Deployment
metadata:
  name: nginx
  labels:
    app: nginx
spec:
  replicas: 1
  selector:
    matchLabels:
      app: nginx
  template:
    metadata:
      labels:
        app: nginx
    spec:
      containers:
      - name: nginx
        image: kdosiodjinud/nginx:2.0.3
        imagePullPolicy: Always
        ports:
          - containerPort: 80
```

Kubernetes nginx_service.yaml

```
apiVersion: v1
kind: Service
metadata:
  name: nginx
spec:
  selector:
    app: nginx
  ports:
  - protocol: TCP
    port: 80
    targetPort:  80
```

I test funkcionality from local with kubectl proxy:
http://localhost:8001/api/v1/namespaces/default/services/http:nginx:/proxy/#!/

Kubernetes **kubectl get pods -A**

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                                                           READY   STATUS    RESTARTS   AGE
default                nginx-84c6ffb78d-srsvn                                         1/1     Running   3          43m
default                php-fpm-5984c4bb56-5rf8v                                       1/1     Running   1          43m
default                postgres-7ffd788bc9-58z7k                                      1/1     Running   11         25h
kube-system            canal-fd6s4                                                    2/2     Running   22         27h
kube-system            coredns-659dc8dcb5-4wv2m                                       1/1     Running   1          45m
kube-system            coredns-659dc8dcb5-sshtt                                       1/1     Running   1          45m
kube-system            etcd-onekube-ip-89-221-220-50.localdomain                      1/1     Running   11         27h
kube-system            kube-apiserver-onekube-ip-89-221-220-50.localdomain            1/1     Running   13         27h
kube-system            kube-controller-manager-onekube-ip-89-221-220-50.localdomain   1/1     Running   11         27h
kube-system            kube-proxy-r84vz                                               1/1     Running   11         27h
kube-system            kube-scheduler-onekube-ip-89-221-220-50.localdomain            1/1     Running   11         27h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper-694557449d-dc6mp                     1/1     Running   12         27h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard-9774cc786-7cgtr                           1/1     Running   11         27h
```

Kubernetes **kubectl get svc -A**

```
NAMESPACE              NAME                        TYPE        CLUSTER-IP       EXTERNAL-IP   PORT(S)                  AGE
default                kubernetes                  ClusterIP   10.96.0.1        <none>        443/TCP                  27h
default                kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.103.115.236   <none>        443/TCP                  25h
default                nginx                       ClusterIP   10.111.150.200   <none>        80/TCP                   26h
default                php-fpm                     ClusterIP   10.100.87.2      <none>        9000/TCP                 26h
default                postgres                    ClusterIP   10.107.164.67    <none>        5432/TCP                 25h
kube-system            kube-dns                    ClusterIP   10.96.0.10       <none>        53/UDP,53/TCP,9153/TCP   27h
kubernetes-dashboard   dashboard-metrics-scraper   ClusterIP   10.103.202.94    <none>        8000/TCP                 27h
kubernetes-dashboard   kubernetes-dashboard        ClusterIP   10.102.77.2      <none>        443/TCP                  27h
```

**Images are public:**
kdosiodjinud/nginx:2.0.3
kdosiodjinud/php-fpm:2.0.6 and kdosiodjinud/php-fpm:2.0.7 (same images with miniedit in app source, I use switch for test this case)

If more information is needed, I will be happy to add it :)

Thank you for the advice

Comment: Hi, have you tried with the FQDN for the php service? (php-fpm.default.svc.cluster.local). You can read more about it here: https://kubernetes.io/docs/concepts/services-networking/dns-pod-service/. `fastcgi_pass php-fpm.default.svc.cluster.local:9000;`

Comment: stp18: I tried and unfortunately still the same. After restart vps works, if i switch php-fpm image, not working... In nginx log i see:
2020/11/21 19:19:59 [error] 30#30: *16 connect() failed (113: Host is unreachable) while connecting to upstream, client: 89.221.220.50, server: , request: "GET / HTTP/1.1", upstream: "fastcgi://10.100.87.2:9000", host: "localhost:8001"

...where 10.100.87.2 is IP service whitch i see in kubectl get svc

Comment: If the error is "host is unreachable" and it's found the Service's IP address, then the DNS layer is working correctly.  It looks like the Service is connected to the Pod correctly.  Is the PHP-FPM server correctly listening on 0.0.0.0:9000?

Comment: My actual information about this: problem is with VPS hosting infrastructure, wait for solution